# NodeJS - standalone application to making user to input data

Tags: node.js

Does NodeJS has any functionality for accepting input via standard input from a user. In Browser based JS we used to use 'prompt' functionality for same but the this would not work on NodeJS standalone app.

```
node one.js

Enter any number:

<program accepts the number and does the processing>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use readline prompt http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: Hi vinayr, while this link may be helpful, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a resource of knowledge for years to come. If this link were to ever break, your answer would be useless. To ensure your post lives on for years to come, use the [edit] link to add an example to the body of your post, leaving the link as a helpful reference and ensuring that link rot won't kill your answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As vinayr said, you should use readline. An example of what you desire:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Input number:", function(numAnswer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  var num = parseInt(numAnswer);
  processingFunctionYouUse(num);
  rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use [stdio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stdio). It is a module that aims to simplify your life with standard input/output. One of its main features is the standard input reading, line by line, and it can be done as follows:

```
var stdio = require('stdio');
stdio.readByLines(function (line) {
    // This function is called for every line while they are being read
}, function (err) {
    // This function is called when the whole input has been processed
});
```

PD: I'm the `stdio` creator. :-)

[image: NPM]
<sub>(source: [nodei.co](https://nodei.co/npm/stdio.png))</sub>